# Building continuous integration environment with git, Jenkins, and Gerrit

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I am building a continuous integration with git, Jenkins and Gerrit. My Jenkins version is 1.620, my Gerrit is 2.11.2 and Gerrit trigger is 2.14.

In Gerrit trigger of Jenkins, I set:

```
hostname: localhost
frontend URL :http://localhost
ssh port :29418
```

and ssh keyfile my path to the private ssh key of Jenkins user on my host. I tested connection and it gave me success.

Besides I didn't touch the advanced settings. But it gave me a warning which goes like this:

```
Gerrit version is a bit old, so not all Gerrit features are enabled. Project created events requires 2.12.
```

**My question is that what is this 2.12 referring to** because my Gerrit is 2.11.2 and it is the latest release and Gerrit trigger is 2.14.